# SQL to find average of dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores the dates of events, and I would like to find the average number of events by the day of the week.

e.g.,

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 |
| 3 | 2021-09-02 |
| 4 | 2021-09-03 |

```
Result:

Wed: 2
Thu: 1
Fri: 1
```

**UPDATE**

I am told that I gave a poor example. Here is another attempt:

There was 1000 events in the month of June. Each event is a row with an ID and a date. There can be multiple events in a day (In the table above, imagine that there are 250 events on 9/1 and 150 on 9/2 and 300 on 9/3, etc.). I would like to know the average number of events for each day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.) for the entire month of June

Yes, I can simply divide by four to find the average for June but I am using a single month as an example. In reality, I am having to average out over several months and would like a solution where I am not having to determine the number of weeks between dates manually (e.g., using a date time calculator or counting the weeks with a calendar).

Here is a query I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(DATEPART(DD, EVENT_DATE) AS 'Event Total', AVG(COUNT(DATEPART(DD, EVENT_DATE)) AS 'Average'

FROM TABLE_1
GROUP BY DATEPART(DD, EVENT_DATE)
```

I'm having difficulty grouping by the days and then finding the average of the grouping. Is this possible with just t-sql?

Comment: [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)/[`DATENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I know to be using those functions, but I can't put the pieces together to get the results I want

Comment: Please show your attempt that averages single numbers. Your sample data looks more like a counts than averages. Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Comment: @HABO I didn't want to create a large table with realistic looking data by hand. I just wanted to give an example of what my data structure look like. Another way to say it is that I have 100 events in June. I want to know the average number of events for each weekenday (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc).

Comment: Ah, now it's getting confusing. If you have events on four Mondays and four Wednesdays, but only one Tuesday, is the average for Tuesday based on the one Tuesday with events or the four Tuesdays in the month? Are the data always summarized by month?

Comment: @HABO It would be the four Tuesdays in the month. The data is always summarized by the day of the week. I want an average of all Tuesday events regardless of month

Comment: That means that you'll need to add code to determine the number of each day-of-the-week that falls between the starting and ending dates for your query (which will need to be explicitly provided). The sample data I provided in my answer had some lines commented out so that there is only one Tuesday date included, therefore it won't return your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of the averaging are still somewhat vague, e.g. should days with no events in June be counted, but this should point you in a suitable direction.  [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b18c1f8a76be32fd9eeaacfdefc3778).

```
declare @SampleEvents as Table ( Id Int Identity, EventDate Date );
insert into @SampleEvents ( EventDate ) values
  ( '20210901' ),
  ( '20210902' ), ( '20210902' ),
  ( '20210903' ), ( '20210903' ), ( '20210903' ),
  ( '20210904' ), ( '20210904' ), ( '20210904' ), ( '20210904' ),
  ( '20210905' ), ( '20210905' ), ( '20210905' ), ( '20210905' ), ( '20210905' ),
  ( '20210906' ),
  ( '20210907' ),
  ( '20210908' ), ( '20210908' ),
  ( '20210909' ), ( '20210909' ), ( '20210909' ),
  ( '20210910' ), ( '20210910' ), ( '20210910' ), ( '20210910' ),
  ( '20210911' ), ( '20210911' ), ( '20210911' ), ( '20210911' ), ( '20210911' ),
  ( '20210912' ),
  ( '20210913' ),
--  ( '20210914' ),
  ( '20210915' ),
  ( '20210916' ),
  ( '20210917' ),
  ( '20210918' ),
  ( '20210919' ),
  ( '20210920' ),
--  ( '20210921' ),
  ( '20210922' ),
  ( '20210923' ),
  ( '20210924' ),
  ( '20210925' ),
  ( '20210926' ),
  ( '20210927' ),
--  ( '20210928' ),
  ( '20210929' ),
  ( '20210930' );
select * from @SampleEvents;

with
  SampleEventsWithDoW as (
    -- Calculate the day-of-week (DoW) for each date.
    -- DoW will always return an integer from   1   to   7   with
    --   1   corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of
    --   DateFirst   or   Language  .)
    select Id, EventDate, ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, EventDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1 as DoW
      from @SampleEvents ),
  SampleEventsSummarizedByDoW as (
    -- Summarize the data by day-of-week.
    select DoW, Count(*) as EventCount, Count( distinct EventDate ) as NumberOfDays
      from SampleEventsWithDoW
      group by DoW )
  -- The following commented-out   select   statements can be used to display the
  --   intermediate results.
--  select * from SampleEventsWithDoW;
--  select * from SampleEventsSummarizedByDoW;
  -- Average the counts.
  -- The   cast   is used to avoid integer division which would result in
  --   values that are probably unacceptable to the OP.
  select DoW, Cast( EventCount as Numeric(10,2) ) / NumberOfDays as AverageEventCount,
    EventCount, NumberOfDays
    from SampleEventsSummarizedByDoW;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Day of Week to get your grouping and count(*) to count all occurrences for the grouping

```
declare @Tmp as table(ID int, date date)

Insert into @Tmp
(ID,    date)
values(1,'2021-09-01')
,(2,    '2021-09-01')
,(3,    '2021-09-02')
,(4,    '2021-09-03')

select count(*) freq,DatePart(WEEKDAY,date) DayOfWeek from @Tmp group by DatePart(WEEKDAY,date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATENAME` to get the name of the week day, then `LEFT` to get the left-most three characters, group on this:

```
SELECT 
LEFT(DATENAME(dw, [date]), 3), 
COUNT([id]) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY 
LEFT(DATENAME(dw, [date]), 3);
```

Comment: Comparing @Golden Lion and this answer, I get the same number for the count but different days for the count. So I would get 1101 for Monday with one query and 1101 for Sunday with the other.